# What do we call a person who criticizes everything? One word for it

Tags: word-request

A word for a person who always criticizes people, and he always claims that he is the righteous.

Comment: Please note that [righteous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/righteous) is an adjective, not a noun. In addition, can you confirm that you mean "righteous" and not "right"?

Answer (score 3):

**Hyper-critical** is a good option to describe such a nature.
The question has been answered well in another forum for English within Stackexchange. You can have a look:
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91506/word-for-the-behavior-of-people-who-complain-at-everything-you-do

Answer (score 0):

Probably a "**hypercritic**" - *a person who is excessively or captiously critical*

Or "**hypercritical**" as an adjective.

You could concatenate "*constantly ratifying*", "*self-righteous*" and "*hypercritic*" to call such a person a "**constantly ratifying self-righteous hypercritic**".

Comment: What does "ratifying" mean here?

Comment: I have upvoted also this answer. I can't see why it has been downlvoted (the figure was -1). Most probably by one or more **hypercritics** or **hypercritical persons**!  (Indeed, there are quite a lot of downvoting "maniacs" in stackexhange!)